# Building NFS Server to be world writable

Tags: nfs, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to build an NFS server on my Raspberry Pi which will be writable by any server on the network. The NFS share is a directory on an external device mounted at boot:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

# This is my external device
/dev/sda1 /data                 ext4    defaults,nofail         0       2
```

I configured my `/etc/exports` as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/exports   
/data *(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/data/share *(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

The User ID and Group ID of 1000 is the pi user and pi group, which owns both /data and /data/share:

```
$ ls -la /data
total 28
drwxrwxrwx  4 pi   pi    4096 Sep 30 08:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Oct  9 15:54 ..
drwx------  2 pi   pi   16384 Sep 25 14:57 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi    4096 Sep 30 08:41 share
```

When I try to mount the share from my Mac, I get the following error:

```
$ mount 192.168.101.10:/data tmp
mount_nfs: can't mount /data from 192.168.101.10 onto /Users/davejlong/Downloads/tmp: Operation not permitted
```

Here is the output of `exportfs -v`

```
$ sudo exportfs -v
/data           <world>(rw,wdelay,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/data/share     <world>(rw,wdelay,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I find my answer immediately after asking the question :facepalm:

It seems that I needed to add the `insecure` option to my exports:

```
$ cat /etc/exports   
/data *(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/data/share *(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

Comment: I assume because it's a Mac.  (The `insecure` option allows connections with a source port outside the 1-1000 range used by traditional unix.  The traditional model generally won't hold anymore... it sounds like you _want_ everyone on that network to have access so it's fine :).